# Problem in submitting Magento Login form

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, template, layout, login

Here is my simple magento login form but I am unable to submit my form. What may be the possible reasons?

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
 Email:
 <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
 Password:
 <input type="password" name="login[password]" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
 <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: where r u using this lo-gin page?

Comment: I need to create a new popup and in that i need to place this login form.

Comment: is any js error occur?when submitting form?

Comment: Still the problem exists. No there is no JS Error

Comment: Since, I am trying to submit the form in a popup, can this cause any problem in form submission?

Comment: you have getting $this->getPostActionUrl() value?

Comment: Sorry, I cant get you?

Comment: means first check action value in firebug

Comment: Okay , Let me check.

Comment: Is your form inside an other form?

Comment: No, that page contains only one form.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're missing a `</form>` tag.  Try this:

```
<?php $custmlogin= new Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login();?>
<form action="<?php echo $custmlogin->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
 Email:
 <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
 Password:
 <input type="password" name="login[password]" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
 <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
```